# Select value not appending via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new to AJAX. I have a Invoice form in RoR in which contains customer,product and service fields. When I select customer name from select option, It should dynamically get few fields to be filled from customer form. similarly for products from products form and service from service form.

```js
$("#customer_name").on('change', function() {
  $(this).valid();
  var customer_name = $('#customer_name').val();

  if ($('#customer_name').val() == 'Add New') {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '/customer_details/new',
      success: function(result) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html(result.html);
      },
      complete: function(result) {
        popup.customerDetail();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/invoices/dropdown',
      data: {
        customer_name: customer_name
      },
      success: function(result) {
        $(".append-customer-details").html(result.html);
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
= fields_for Invoice.new do |f|
  = f.label :customer_detail_id,"Customer Name"
  = f.select(:customer_detail_id, CustomerDetail.collect_customer_name,{},{prompt: "Select customer", class: "selectpicker form-control", id: "customer_name", "data-live-search": "true"})
```

problem is once the page is submitted or after a refresh the select options are not displaying.so the fields depend on the select options are also cannot be displayed.I don't know how to pass the select values to the JS.can someone please help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What this gives `result.html` ? `console.log(result.html);`

Comment: it gives dynamically displaying customer-id, address and delivery address given  at the "customer-detail" form to this "Invoice" form

Comment: use  `$('#myModal .modal-body').html(result)`  if you are recieiving html in result and if you are getting data in json form use json.Parse(result)